# Error "Yajra \ Pdo \ Oci8 \ Exceptions \ Oci8Exception ORA-24415: Missing or null username." Using Laravel5.6

Tags: php, oracle, laravel-5.6, oci8

I am not able to connect to the database that is returning this error. In the application I have to use two databases, one mysql (is working) and the other oracle.

System Information:

- win7 x64
- laravel 5.6
- php 7.1.9
- oci 2.1.7
- Instant Clien 12.1

Archive oracle.php

```
return [
'oracle' => [
    'driver'         => 'oracle',
    'tns'            => env('DB_TNS', '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dboraclescan-listener.intranet)(PORT = 1521))
                            (CONNECT_DATA =
                            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                            (SERVICE_NAME = PROD)))'),
    'host'           => env('DB_HOST', 'dboraclescan-listener.intranet'),
    'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
    'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
    'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME', '****'),
    'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD', '***'),
    'charset'        => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
    'prefix'         => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
    'prefix_schema'  => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
    'server_version' => env('DB_SERVER_VERSION', '11g'),
  ],
 ];
```

Archive database.php

```
'oracle' => [
        'driver'         => 'oracle',
        'tns'            => env('DB_TNS', '(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = dboraclescan-listener.intranet)(PORT = 1521))
                                (CONNECT_DATA =
                                (SERVER = DEDICATED)
                                (SERVICE_NAME = PROD)))'),
        'host'           => env('DB_HOST', 'dboraclescan-listener.intranet'),
        'port'           => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'database'       => env('DB_DATABASE', 'PROD'),
        'username'       => env('DB_USERNAME', '***'),
        'password'       => env('DB_PASSWORD', '***'),
        'charset'        => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
        'prefix'         => env('DB_PREFIX', 'ijrm'),
        'prefix_schema'  => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
        'server_version' => env('DB_SERVER_VERSION', '11g'),
    ],
```

Do I need some configuration somewhere else?

Comment: Well, you're using env() so what do you have set in your .env file?

Comment: My env file only have the mysql configuration which is the main database.
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=newportal
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Then you don't want to be using the same environmental variables for both...

Comment: Not really, configurations are different between them.

Comment: But yet you're using the same env call for both...  Do you not see that?

Comment: I would then have to modify the oracle.php file to not use env. Or modify env to receive oracle settings

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Devon, I have modified the env file to send the settings to the database.php file.

```
ORACLE_CONNECTION=oracle
ORACLE_HOST=dboraclescan-listener.intranet
ORACLE_PORT=1521
ORACLE_DATABASE=PROD
ORACLE_USERNAME=***
ORACLE_PASSWORD=***
```

Archive database.php

```
'oracle' => [
            'driver'         => 'oracle',
            'host'           => env('ORACLE_HOST', ''),
            'port'           => env('ORACLE_PORT', '1521'),
            'database'       => env('ORACLE_DATABASE', ''),
            'username'       => env('ORACLE_USERNAME', ''),
            'password'       => env('ORACLE_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'        => env('ORACLE_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
            'prefix'         => env('ORACLE_PREFIX', ''),
            'prefix_schema'  => env('ORACLE_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
            'server_version' => env('ORACLE_SERVER_VERSION', '11g'),
        ],
```

Comment: That's not the approach I would use.  You can  add different environmental variables in your .env file, like ORACLE_USERNAME instead of DB_USERNAME.   For VCS purposes, I wouldn't store credentials in a config file.

Comment: How would an env file look for this setting?

Comment: What do you mean?  Just add new lines with different attribute names in the .env file and use those new attribute names in your config in an env() function call.

Comment: Since I am new to laravel, I did not understand what I had said. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer still is using the old DB_ environmental variables in the env() calls...